# Term For Receive Antenna Using Lorentz Force?

Tags: antenna-theory

Since:

$$\vec F = q \left(-\nabla \phi - \frac{\partial \vec A}{\partial t} + \vec v \times \left( \nabla \times \vec A \right) \right)$$

It would seem that a receive antenna with a current density **J** whose velocity field was **v** would produce enhanced reception.  Is this correct?  If so, there must be a technical name for this kind of antenna.  What is that name?

Note:  I chose the potentials description of the Lorentz force equation to expose all components of the EMF in a single expression. Conduction band electrons of the receive antenna are experiencing a force that changes with time resulting from the incident EM wave. I understand that $-\nabla \phi = 0$ when Tx and Rx are exactly parallel and orthogonally positioned.

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Cleaned up my comments to concentrate on the two core questions: 1. Do I understand correctly that this is the Helmholtz equation applied to the classical Lorentz force formula? 2. Where do you see the improved reception come from, what's the mechanical force on charges got to do with that?

Comment: That is merely the Lorentz Force equation written in terms of the Vector $\vec{A}$ and Scalar $\phi$ potentials instead of the more common form using $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$.  The division of vector fields $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ into potential fields $\vec{A}$ and $\phi$ is normally referred to as the Helmholtz Partition Theorem.

Comment: @K7PEH yep, noticed that tonight, hence my Helmholtz eq question. What's still unclear to me is my 2. question, namely, what the Lorentz force should have to do with reception.

Comment: I don't have a derivation of the Helmholtz equation from the Lorentz force equation.  I chose the potentials description of the Lorentz force equation because an Rx antenna works because the conduction band electrons are experiencing a force that changes with time resulting from the incident EM wave, and I wanted to expose all components of the wave in a single expression.  (I understand that $$-\nabla \phi = 0$$ when Tx and Rx are exactly parallel and orthogonally positioned.)

Comment: Since reception is usually limited by noise rather than sensitivity in practice, I'm not sure such an antenna (if it's possible) would enhance reception. I'd guess the extra current would add more noise than its worth.

Comment: The Helmholtz Equation is merely the wave time-independent wave equation.  This is typically derived from the space and time wave equation using separation of variables method to establish wave equation dependent on space coordinates only and a wave equation dependent on time coordinate only.  The space coordinate version is the Helmholtz Equation.

Comment: Also, the wave equation falls right out of Maxwell's equations (differential form) by taking the curl of the curl vector functions of either $\vec{E}$ or $\vec{B}$ and then using the vector identities for $\nabla \times \nabla \times \vec{E}$ you arrive at the wave equation for either $\vec{E}$ or $\vec{B}$.  You never make use of the Lorentz Equation.

Comment: And one more post -- I think the OP might be thinking of a traveling wave antenna but I am only guessing as I can't derive that information from his question itself.  But, these are typically used for improved receiving antennas such as the Beverage antenna.

Comment: Is it not the case that the direction of the EMF would be orthogonal to **v**?  In that event the voltage difference due to **v** would be cross-sectional to the "wire".  Correct?  Is that how the traveling wave antenna works?

Comment: The Force on the electron moving in a conductor due to Lorentz Force is partly the result of $\vec{E}$ field and partly the result of $\vec{B}$ field.  However, the $\vec{B}$ field force component is so weak in comparison to the $\vec{E}$ field that it can be ignored.  I have done this very calculation as an undergrad physics major.  If my memory serves me, it was outlined in the text "Electricity & Magnetism" by Purcell and part of the Berkeley Physics Course set.  In my case, this was way back in 1966.

Comment: @JamesBowery either you model the electrons as particles that can experience a force,or you consider them  "delocated in conduction band".If you apply the electric pot. to Schrödinger's equation for a free electron in a metal lattice,you'll notice that by changing the potential (typically, denoted $V$ in the eq.) the probability density function for the place of electrons "shifts" it's "point of gravity" around – you can probably *interpret* that as the electrons being accelerated(by a *force*),but that would basically complicate the relatively simple model of electrons subject to $\vec E$.

Comment: @K7PEH I think you're probably correct as the drift velocity in a conductor is typically a very small fraction of the speed of light and the total charge moving in such an antenna wouldn't be enough to compensate.  Moreover, as I pointed out in my response to your answer proposing the traveling wave antenna, the direction of the current is such that it would have no effect on the potential difference across the length of the antenna -- only its cross sectional width.  So wouldn't "the answer" to my question be, "No such antenna hence no such term."?

Answer (score 3):

I will take a stab at a guess to suggest the OP is looking for a common type of receiving antenna (Rx) known as a Traveling Wave Antenna.  As I mentioned in my comment, the popular so-called "Top-Band" receiving antennas are Beverage Antennas which is a kind of Traveling Wave Antenna.

Traveling Wave Antennas are known as Broadband Antennas because their bandwidth is usually wider than a resonant antenna (e.g. Dipole).  The Bandwidth for antennas can be measured in several different ways but for Traveling Wave Antennas it is usually defined by:
$$
Bandwidth = \frac{f_U}{f_L}
$$
Where $f_U$ and $f_L$ are upper and lower frequencies of the range of acceptable performance of the antenna (you get to define what "acceptable" means).

A Traveling Wave Antenna is so called because the current is traveling along the conductors.  This is different from the typical Dipole resonant antenna where the current is in "Standing Waves" on the conductors.  Traveling Wave antennas are also known as just "Wave" antennas.

I have worked through solutions using both analytical and numerical methods of resonant antennas.  Actually, only the thin-wire (where cross-section is ignored) dipole have I done using purely analytical means.  For numerical solution I have used both the Method of Moments (used by popular NEC2/NEC4) and experimented with some FTDT methods.

However, I have never worked on solving for the currents of a Traveling Wave Antenna so I do not know much about that.  However, in scanning some of my books in my library, I have never seen the Lorentz Force being used to somehow model the current (guessing that is what the OP is referring to).  Does not mean it is not possible though.  In fact, solving physics problems from so-called "First Principles" is often a popular endeavor although many times includes complexities that are not worth the effort.

In solving for antenna solutions, you usually work to obtain a good representation or approximation of the current on the antenna conductors (I am referring to wire antennas here, whether resonant or traveling wave). This current is the unknown and once you have the current you can solve the Helmholtz Integrals for both the vector potential $\vec{A}$ and the scalar potential $\vec{\phi}$.  Using these, you can compute the fields $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{H}$ and from those compute many other antenna parameters (etc, gain, radiation field).

So, the key is the current $I$, or current density $\vec{J}$ and you usually need $\vec{J}$ when the geometry of the conductors are an important part of the antenna.

In one of my books, "Antenna Theory and Design" by Stutzman and Thiele, they begin their discussion of modeling long wire (a kind of traveling wave) antennas using a constant current as:
$$
I_t(z) = I_m\,e^{- j \beta z}
$$
Where the $z$ coordinate is along the conductive wire and $I_m$ is just some maximum current value.  $\beta$ is a phase constant.

The discussion continues on from that simple start to consider more complicated traveling wave antennas (e.g. Rhombic).

I recommend the Stutzman & Thiele book as a starting place.  Its handling of traveling wave antennas is more extensive and detailed than in other books I have such as "Antennas For All Applications" by Krauss & Marhefka or "Antenna Theory" by Balanis.

Comment: I think the geometry of the conductor must be crucial in this case since the direction of the force $q \left(  \vec v \times \left( \nabla \times \vec A \right) \right)$ would be at right angle to the "long wire"'s corresponding $\vec J$ thence $I_t(z)$.  Otherwise the wire would just physically vibrate at the radio frequency.  Correct?

Comment: The one-dimensional modeling of wire antennas are shown to be pretty accurate for far-field.  Usually, the dimension of the conductors effects other parameters such as impedance, bandwidth, etc.  I strongly suggest you consider studying a good (graduate level) antenna analysis text such as those I mentioned and get into the gory details.  I am very suspicious of your reliance on Lorentz Force but don't let me dissuade you from digging deep into the math and modeling.

Comment: A Beverage antenna terminated in its characteristic impedance has a low VSWR throughout a wide frequency range. http://www.w0btu.com/Beverage_antennas.html

Comment: @K7PEH in order for the current along the z coordinate, hence reception, to be affected by the B field of the EM wave, the velocity of the detecting charge must be orthogonal to the z coordinate.  That is what I mean by "the geometry of the conductor" being crucial.  As the z coordinate is the same dimension as the wire this disqualifies your answer.